# Interpreting huge spike in learning curve MSE for specific training size

Tags: regression, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I am running a regression and using sci-kit-learn and Matplotlib to plot learning curves for training and validation sets in 5-fold cross-validation. I started out plotting a handful of different sized datasets, indicated by the vertical dotted lines in this plot (note that the y-axis has been inverted since the scoring metric was `neg_mean_squared_error`):

[image: learning curve 1]

Noticing the spike in the validation error curve, I then plotted the learning curve for every percentile from 1 to 100, which produced this huge spike in MSE on the validation set:

[image: learning curve 2]

Below are the raw numbers in the cross-validation scores behind this spike:

[image: scores]

I am having trouble interpreting what this says about my data. The data was collected through a manual data entry process, so it is likely that there could be outliers, though I did some pre-processing to remove extreme outliers (z-score > 5) from both the independent and target features. I can't get my head round why the particular training size of 76 produces such huge errors in the validation set, which then diminishes so quickly as you increase or decrease the training size from m=76.

For info my code to produce the learning curve was roughly this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

t_sizes, t_scores, v_scores = learning_curve(estimator=LinearRegression(), X=X, y=y, train_sizes=np.arange(0.01, 0.99, 0.01), cv=5, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", shuffle=True)
```

Any help in debugging or interpreting these results would be greatly appreciated.